# how to search through directories for empty text files in Bash?

Tags: bash

so I am doing a small project as I am learning Bash, and the instructions say:

Some of the files in our project which end with the suffix, .txt, have no content in them. List the files, across all the continent directories, that end with .txt that have no content and save the listing in a file, empty_files.txt, in the todo/ directory.

I'm not sure how to do this without and if statement, any ideas?

I ave tried '''grep -R '.txt' * | wc''' but this only counts the words, and doesnt tell me what files have no words.

Comment: Read the `find` man page, and look for `-empty`

Comment: The duplicate question's answer tells you how ho do it *without* `find` but the question also reveals how to do it with `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [find](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command to do the trick.

```
    find /absolute/directory/path -type f -size 0

    $ find /home/playground/test-empty/ -type f -size 0
    /home/playground/test-empty/emptyness/file
    /home/playground/test-empty/emptyness/file2
    /home/playground/test-empty/more-empty-files/1
    /home/playground/test-empty/more-empty-files/2
```